# moving mysql db from linux to windows

Tags: windows, linux, mysql

I am trying to move my database from linux server to my windows local machine. I created a  dump of mysql and tried to restore on my windows machine. when script file (dump file) executes in local machine, it is raising error no. [1105.](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,19755,27901#msg-27901) on many tables. 
Any help is appreciated. thanks !

Comment: You might also install Linux on your local machine, perhaps in a VM. This would give you an environment more similar to what your sever has.

Comment: @dotnetrocks - so what did you find?  Is your export working?  What was the problem?

Comment: well, the problem was because of play framework. It created all the tables one more time in the database with small case table names. When I export this script to my windows local machine, it recognizes they are same tables ( windows ignore case difference in table names). So, I manually deleted duplicated set of tables and it is working now !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes: you can absolutely import a MySql database from Linux to Windows.  And yes, a dump file is absolutely the best way to do it :)

2) The question is "why am I getting Mysql error 1105 on import"?

3) Unfortunately, this error is somewhat generic.  There are many different possible root causes.

The link you cited gives *many* different reasons:

- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,19755,305448#msg-305448

  For example:

> In my case, the problem was that the referenced field was not marked
>   as unique, and thus returned this (unrelated) error message.

SUGGESTION:

Identify the specific table, cut/paste the sql dump command directly into mysql, and debug that way.

ADDENDUM:

1) Please cut/paste the *exact* error message.

If possible, please

2) cut/paste the SQL line in your dbexport that's causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

You may experience problems doing this - Windows uses a case-insensitive filesystem while Linux is case sensitive.  MyIASM might be breaking because of this - the table names are directly related to the file names..